# Pass ambiguous rows into table in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm a little confused in Lua. I want to take 3 headers in an unspecified row index and transfer them to the table.
In order not to ramble too much, I will give some of the lines as examples instead of the code I use.

```
uptade = [[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - … Microsoft.VCRedist.2008.x64                   9.0.30729.6161      winget 
Java 8 Update 391                             {71324AE4-039E-4CA4-87B4-2F32180391F0}        8.0.3910.13          
Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems … {7B63012A-4AC6-40C6-B6AF-B24A84359DD5}        8.93.0.0             
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - … {8220EEFE-38CD-377E-8595-13398D740ACE}        9.0.30729            
GiliSoft Screen Recorder Pro                  {85B92051-32EF-61AA-AB7C-24B0B2DB29AC}_is1    13.0.0               
Security Update for Microsoft Office 2016 (K… {90160000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}_Offic… Unknown         ]]

-- result

resTbl = { {"Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable", "9.0.30729.6161","winget"},
{"Java 8 Update 391", "8.0.3910.13",""},
{"Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems","8.93.0.0", ""},
{"Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable", "9.0.30729", ""},
{"GiliSoft Screen Recorder Pro", "13.0.0", ""},
{"Security Update for Microsoft Office 2016", "Unknown", ""}}
```

How can I parse this into a table?

EDIT:
Until a better solution comes along, here is the solution I found:
I printed the CMD output to a ".cvs" file.
I realized that; at certain intervals as "Name..Id..Version..Available..Source "
`(string.sub(1,39) -->>40,78..79,98..99,113..114,125..)`
is listed.
I read with these intervals and transferred each row to a table in 5 sections.

```
s1=line:sub(1,39) s2=line:sub(40,78)...
aa2 = {s1,s2,s3,s4,s5} listTbl1[#listTbl1 + 1] = aa2
print(listTbl1[1][1].."---"..listTbl1[1][2])
```

The only problem is that CMD remains visible on the screen for 8-12 seconds, depending on the number of programs.
If anyone has a better solution, please reply.
Thanks.

Comment: I would iterate over lines and use some regex, e.g., `^([^{]*){[^{]*}\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*(.*)` or similar.  (First capture has excess spaces and Unknown case not handled yet)

Comment: @Luke100000 , thanks..
Please state your recommendation in the code.
"line:match" shows an error in the line you gave.